# Download url angular

Tags: angular, download, blob

I recorded a webcam video using angular 8. Now what I need is, instead of direct download, to send it directly to a specific folder. Here is my code :

```js
mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{    
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
    chunks = [];
    let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    vidSave.src = videoURL;  
     var file = new File([blob], 'video.mp4', {
         type: 'video/mp4'
     });
    invokeSaveAsDialog(file);
}
```

My scenario is, when the user speaks to our application, we record his video and send it directly to our server. I need to send video directly to specific folder (c:/destnation-folder), not download it, you understand please? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to save the video in your server, or do you want to save the video in a specific folder of the user?

Comment: i have the video in my donwloads folder after this (invokeSaveAsDialog(file);) , now i need to move it but angular cant copy files , now what i need to do?  should i create a job or a thread that accomplish this task